# Algolia: getting data with CURL (PHP) returns different from the example results with places.js

Tags: php, curl, algolia

I am trying to get places search with Algolia but with my server. I tried to reproduce the search exactly as it does the provided example (https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html - the first simple input), but the system returns a little different result. In particular - if you enter `Paris` in the input you will see that first it shows the Paris city, and then other results, which is a correct way. But when I do the very same request with CURL it returns `Paris 17e Arrondissement`, then `Paris 8e Arrondissement` and others. The actual Paris city appears only as the 5th result.

```
$cURLConnection = curl_init('https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20Algolia%20Places%201.18.2&x-algolia-application-id=MYAPPID&x-algolia-api-key=MYAPIKEY');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"params":"hitsPerPage=10&language=en&query='.$keyword.'"}');

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
exit($result);
```

What could be the reason for such a behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the required parameters. The problem was that the aroundLatLngViaIP is on by default, making the results show results close to the server location. I also did the code the right way this time through the REST API documentation and did the gzip compression to speedup getting the results:

```
$cURLConnection = curl_init('https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"query": "'.$keyword.'", "language" : "fr", "aroundLatLngViaIP" : "false", "hitsPerPage" : "10"}');

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'X-Algolia-Application-Id: MyAppKey',
    'X-Algolia-API-Key: MyAPIKey',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host: places-dsn.algolia.net'
];

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
if ( (ord($result[0])==0x1f) && (ord($result[1])==0x8b) ) {
    // skip header and ungzip the data
    $result = gzinflate(substr($result,10));
}
```